# How to decompyle exe to py which compiled by Nuitka

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, decompiling, nuitka

I used:
nuitka --standalone script.py
After this command I got folder with exe file and another files, as in pyinstaller
The problem is that when creating an exe through pyinstaller, you can get back the source code using uncompyle6. When creating an exe via nuitka --standalone, there is no base_library.rar, as in pyinstaller, where is the code in the pyc file. How do I get the source code?
My english so bad, I used google translater

Realizing that the pyc file with the code is nowhere to be found, I decided that it was in the exe file (as pyinstaller --onefile), I tried pyinstxtractor.py however nothing happened

Comment: I don't believe you can do that, at least not in any standard way - the thing is, Nuitka doesn't just pack a Python runtime into an `exe` like pyinstaller, but instead it transpiles your Python code into C and then compiles that C code using one of the C compilers available on your system.

Comment: Just have a look at this [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/10fvv70/can_we_decompile_an_exe_file_compiled_with_nuitka/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on Reddit.